# resizing an uiimage before writing it to documents directory

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a question.I need to resize the image when I take an image using camera and picking the image from the photo library using uiimagepickercontroller and then write that resized image to the documents directory. So please help me with some reference on how to resize an uiimage.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();    
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
NSString *path = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"resizedImage.jpg"];
[UIImageJPGRepresentation(newImage, 1.0) writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But what is newsize? what is newsize.width and newsize.height? Could u please give me some more details.

Comment: newSize is a CGSize e.g. CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(20, 10);, where the width is 20 px and the height 10 px. Set newSize to the size you want your image to be.

Comment: what is the image here? is it my actual image name? the image which is not resized right?

Comment: Yeah, `image` is the full-sized image.

Comment: Thank you so much, it was great help for me.I was able to come over the issue.

Comment: I have one more question, I need to allow the user to add photo when he taps on the uiimageview by adding uitapguesturerecognzer and popping up the actionsheet with buttons like take photo and choose photo, instead of clicking on an uibutton which is in the uiview and presenting uiimagepickercontroller.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Trevor's library for more effects, not only resizing - [Resize Image the Right Way](http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I was able to come over it.

Comment: You are welcome. By the way image operations by libraries from this http link are much faster than use UIGraphics*ImageContext so you can save battery on device a bit. Tested on iOS 5 also.